# Which of the following sets maps onto (i) the right half plane and (ii) the left half plane under the map $f(z) = \sin z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Which of the following sets maps onto (i) the right half plane and (ii) the left half plane under the map $f(z) = \sin z$

1. $\{z : 0<Re(z)\leq\frac{π}{2}\}$
2. $\{z : 0<Im(z)\leq\frac{π}{2}\}$
3. $\{z : \frac{-π}{2}\leq Re(z)\leq\frac{π}{2}\}$
4. $\{z : \frac{-π}{2}\leq Im(z)\leq\frac{π}{2}\}$

My Attempt:

$f(z) = \sin z = \sin (x+iy) = \sin x  \cos iy + \cos x  \sin iy = \sin x  \cosh y + i cos x 
 \sinh y$
Here $Re(f(z)) = \sin x  \cosh y$ and $Im(f(z)) = cos x 
 \sinh y$

If I take $z = x+iy$ then $Re(z) = x$ and $Im(z) = y$. So for $z = \frac{π}{2}+i0, \sin \frac{π}{2} = 1$ that lies on Real Axis.

Also Let $f(z)= \sin z = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}$

I don't know how to draw the graphs of given options under $\sin z$. Please help me.

Comment: Try to separate out the cases: what is the condition for something to be in the left or right half-plane? When is $\sin(x)\cdot \cosh(y)$ larger than 0 and when is it smaller?

Comment: Is your comment mean ? " Q.1  Which of the following sets maps onto the right half plane under the map $f(z) = \sin z$

1.  $\{z : 0<Re(z)\leq\frac{π}{2}\}$

2.  $\{z : 0<Im(z)\leq\frac{π}{2}\}$

3.  $\{z : \frac{-π}{2}\leq Re(z)\leq\frac{π}{2}\}$

4.  $\{z : \frac{-π}{2}\leq Im(z)\leq\frac{π}{2}\}$

Q.2 Which of the following sets maps onto the left half plane under the map $f(z) = \sin z$

1.  $\{z : 0<Re(z)\leq\frac{π}{2}\}$

2.  $\{z : 0<Im(z)\leq\frac{π}{2}\}$

3.  $\{z : \frac{-π}{2}\leq Re(z)\leq\frac{π}{2}\}$

4.  $\{z : \frac{-π}{2}\leq Im(z)\leq\frac{π}{2}\}$"